# ANN Show Different Output Each Run on Matlab

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I run **ANN** on **MATLAB**, and the output of ANN is not consistent every time I run it? How to overcome this problem. I used same data and ANN structure.

```
clear;
clc;
load ('C:\USers\ARMA\Desktop\DATA.txt'); 
data=DATA; 
N=length(data); 
DT=data;
X=DT(1:N,1:2);
Y=DT(1:N,3);
H=3;

net=newff(minmax(X),[H,1],{'logsig','purelin'},'traingdx');

net=init(net);
net.trainparam.Ir=0.9;
net.trainparam.mc=0.1;
net.trainparam.epochs=10000;
net.trainparam.goal=0.001;
net.trainparam.show=1000;
[net,tr]=train(net,X,Y);
plotperform(tr)
```

Comment: That depends. Are you **training** or **performing predictions**?  Also, please show whatever code you're using to reconstruct your problem. Right now, no one can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Update your post please.

Comment: @rayryeng is there any reson for it?

Answer (score 1):

The ANN toolbox uses a randomised initial values as initial weights and biases. So apparently the results are sensitive to them.
You need to fix them before training to achieve similar results.

Comment: How to fix the toolbox?

Comment: Set the random seed with `rng`

Comment: @rayryeng where is random seed? and what is rng?